# How to prevent corosion damage in a salt air environment?

Tags: physical-environment

I am fortunate enough to live at the beach and am a big electronic gadget guy.   Almost every afternoon there is a solid onshore wind that blows in the house.   The dust that comes off the beach has a high salt content and the area is very humid.   I am worried that this wet, salty air is going to corrode every piece of exposed metal in my electronic gear.

Has anyone heard / seen / done anything to prevent this from happening?

(I've seen things like computers run in a tank of oil, but I am looking for a less drastic solution)

Answer (score 5):

Electronics manufacturers that have to cope with this environment varnish their PCBs. The main cost on a production line is the time to mask off the connectors rather than the cost of the varnish. You can buy spray on varnish and it doesn't always need an oven to cure it.

When a really heavy duty protective layer is required, this is called conformal coating, and can be achieved by dipping the PCB into the coating. Again, it's the masking thats the expensive part (time consuming), and thicker coatings may require an oven bake to cure them. 
The ability of hot components to dissipate the heat will decrease when they are coated, so then a derating factor applies to power components. This is one of the reasons that industrial electronics is more expensive than consumer electronics.

The main reliability issues you will have are on contacts of connectors and switches. Decide if you'd rather get ruggidised, marine type equipment eg Panasonic Toughbook or just replace things when they fail, at a higher rate than normal. It may well not be worth that much effort to protect consumer grade items which will obselete in a short period anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Keep your system free of dust.**

Dust attracts moisture, and holds it against components. Moisture combines with salt to corrode metal. Blow the system out with compressed air once a month. Change your furnace+A/C filters monthly.

**Keep the humidity low.** See above.

**Avoid wide temperature swings**

Fast changes in temperature, up or down, causes condensation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend wiping down the exposed areas with WD-40.  This may not be an option or other smaller gadgets, but for bigger things that sit exposed to the environment everyday, this may help you out.

http://www.wd40.com/faqs/

Here's a list of 1,997 uses from the Tacoma Wheelmen's Bicycle Club: http://www.wd40.com/files/pdf/wd-40_2042538679.pdf

some of the unofficial uses:

- Protects snow shovels from the
  effects of salt
- Protects bike frame
  from salt water corrosion
- Prevents
  salt damage on aluminum exterior
  components of personal watercrafts

If it works for you, perhaps you could drop them a line and add yours to the list!

Comment: WD-40, or Stoddard fluid, ranks at the bottom for rust protection. However as a penetrant, it is good for getting between electrical connections and creating resistance. If you want a good rust protectant with a great history, reputation and the scientific studies to back it up, use Fluid Film. Just don't use it on electronics either.

Comment: I would never cover anything (except the a shovel perhaps) with WD40.  WD40 will cause dust and debris to stick to whatever its coating.  That and WD40 dries out leaving gummy residue behind.

Answer (score 0):

Three sentences for you :

1. Get a dry box.
2. Close your windows.
3. Wipe gadgets with dry cloth regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I live right next to the sea, and have for.. 20 years  and well, other than copper, we haven't that many problems(well we have had fungus issues, and dust issues, and users applying too much force but never corrosion related failures of electronics). If you're really paranoid, i suppose i'd suggest investing in silica gel.

Answer (score 0):

silica jell packets can be place inside your electronics, This will not really help with salt, but it will reduce moisture. You do need to replace them regularly. Most, but not all, such packets can either be baked or microwaved to dry them out for reuse.

Most of our problems will be with connectors. A good can of contact cleaner can help.

Answer (score 0):

Where we live, it's hot and humid and a lot of salt breeze.  It really does depend on all these details and then actual nearness and exposure.  Something that is 30 meters from the water and exposed lasts 1/4 of the time as something 100 meters from the sea with a wall between.  Keep your gear as far out of the sea breeze as possible.

I found that keeping dust down also really helps.  In addition, I have sealed boxes with gun safe dryers in them for gear that is stored. The dryers have silica beads and you plug 'em in to dry 'em out, then into in the sealed bin with the gear. Rinse and repeat monthly.

For my computers, router etc, stuff that can be kept on, I keep as much as possible inside a cabinet with limited air flow (not sealed) and let the heat they generate drive the moisture off.  Really helps. Probably ten degrees hotter inside and I'm convinced that the heat damages the gear far less than the moisture that is driven off.

Stuff that is in the open, keep the air moving so that dampness does not accumulate.  Fans.

Be prepared to replace as needed.

Comment: This describes what you practice, but doesn't really describe how effective these steps are.  Can you add that to your answer?  Maybe compare your results to what neighbors experience?

Answer (score 0):

Full Submersion in Mineral Oil, use copper heat pipe to copper fins & fans to cool mineral oil. Seal whole thing air tight. Nothing gets in, nothing gets out. Occasionally clean external copper using standard copper-cleaning solutions.

Exmaple of a similar project: [Mineral Oil Computer](https://www.pugetsystems.com/submerged.php)